# Color Text and BG of Verbatim, without affecting `fancyvrb` line numbers

Tags: color, verbatim, fancyvrb

The MWE below aims to color the text and background of a `Verbatim` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{PYtxt}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.95}
\definecolor{PYbgc}{rgb}{0.15,0.16,0.13}

\newsavebox{\PYbgbox}
\newenvironment{PYcolorbox}%
 {\noindent%
  \begin{lrbox}{\PYbgbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}%
  \color{PYtxt}}%
 {\ignorespacesafterend%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \colorbox{PYbgc}{\usebox{\PYbgbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{PYcolorbox}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},numbers=left,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1+
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
\end{Verbatim}
\end{PYcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The problem with the code above is that line numbers produced by `fancyvrb` are also colored white, and cannot be seen when compiled.

How may I do both of the following (but not at the same time):

- independently change the text color and line number color?
- expand `PYcolorbox` to the left to include the (white) line numbers?

Alternative code method: adding `formatcom=\color{white}` to the `Verbatim` arguments yields white text (including line numbers), but also affects the bottom margin of the color background.

The goal would be to use this in tandem with `Pygments`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a redefinition of `\theFancyVerbLine` you can change to color for the numbers independently; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{PYtxt}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.95}
\definecolor{PYbgc}{rgb}{0.15,0.16,0.13}

\newsavebox{\PYbgbox}
\newenvironment{PYcolorbox}%
 {\noindent%
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{%
\textcolor{red!80!black}{\small\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\PYbgbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}%
  \color{PYtxt}}%
 {\ignorespacesafterend%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \colorbox{PYbgc}{\usebox{\PYbgbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{PYcolorbox}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},numbers=left,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1+
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
\end{Verbatim}
\end{PYcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder, however, if you wouldn't be better off using a package such as [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) or [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) which offer you colored backgrounds out of the box. Specially `minted` might be useful here since it uses Pygments.

Comment: Thank you! The reason I'm not using `minted` is because I am trying to extend Pygments functionality. [I've documented the change you helped with here](https://bitbucket.org/jambonrose/pygments-main/wiki/Text%20Color%20Ignored), if you are curious.